# How to use the Photoshop PSD design file in your xCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, photoshop

I'm going to creat an iOS app from UI design to implementation, I want to make my app looks better, so i googled a lot and find people saying to create a PSD file with your app views first, so here comes to my question:

1) If i had that PSD file, how do i use it in my app?

2) Is there a general way to use that PSD file for all the elements I created?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To sketch the navigation and graphic design of an iPhone app, it's common to do wireframing, and then a version in Photoshop. If you have a PSD file, you'll have to cut each element manually and export as PNG 8 or 24. To automatically export the graphics you would need slices and scripting, too much work if you are not familiar with photoshop so just do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

The PSD File contains your photoshop readable source material and cannot be used in your iOS application. You have to export / save your PDF files save a PNG or jpeg to use it.

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks. I do see people mention to export the images from PSD, if i export the images, can you tell me how do i reference it in the xCode? Interface Builder? I don't see any attributes for a UIButton(for example) to change its image. Any code do i need to put there, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some slicing, i.e. divide the interface described in the PSD into smaller PNG images.

#### You will probably need

- The designer who made the PSD.
- Adobe Photoshop.

#### These are the broad steps that you need to take.

1. The designer needs to tell you what each element of his design is supposed to do.
2. As a developer you will need to decide how each element is going into your app (Button, Label, image, table)
3. Pick out the components you need for each element (outline, fill, shadow, etc)
4. Choose the corresponding layers,in the PSD, to those components.
5. save those layers for web(Choose PNG-24, keep transparency)

Answer (score 0):

You can export the PSD elements to XCode using a photoshop script. this is easy and simple. All you need to do is follow the steps and it will import the files to your .storyboard file.

[PSD to Xcode Script by TampestVision](http://www.tempestvision.com/psdtoxcode/)