# Importing PSD files in Xcode

Tags: xcode, png, jpeg, photoshop, psd

I use Adobe Photoshop CS6 to make all of my images that I use on my apps (buttons, photos etc.) and I want to use those images on Xcode. Xcode loads the image, I build my app with it but when I run it, **there is nothing at the Image Well**. Is there any specific method or way that I can import *.psd files into Xcode and use them? Because when I use a *.jpg or *.png file is shows a large white area that doesn't look nice.

Comment: I don't think you can use PSD's in apps. Stick with png.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the Photoshop PSD design file in your xCode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980048/how-to-use-the-photoshop-psd-design-file-in-your-xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode can't use .PSD files.  You need to export your .PSD into a flat standard image file such .png or .jpg.

Comment: how can we do this ?